# How to display colored text in the terminal?

Tags: objective-c, unix

How can I display colored text on the terminal from a ObjectiveC command line application?

Is there a portable way that will work both on iTerm and Terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a command line project and use this one as a starter. When compiling and running it you should see colors in the terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define KNRM  "\x1B[0m"
#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN  "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define KBLU  "\x1B[34m"
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN  "\x1B[36m"
#define KWHT  "\x1B[37m"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    printf("%sred\n", KRED);
    printf("%sgreen\n", KGRN);
    printf("%syellow\n", KYEL);
    printf("%sblue\n", KBLU);
    printf("%smagenta\n", KMAG);
    printf("%scyan\n", KCYN);
    printf("%swhite\n", KWHT);
    printf("%snormal\n", KNRM);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you type `set` in Terminal you’ll probably see:

```
TERM=xterm-color
```

Among others. The “xterm-color” is an old way of saying what control and escape sequences the terminal will respond to, if you look that up you’ll find lots of fun things.